# How to create multiple dynamic variables at once?

Tags: dynamic

With the following code:

```
x[1] = 0;
Checkbox[Dynamic[x[1]], {0, 1}]
Dynamic[x[1]]
```

I can create the dynamic variable `x[1]` and it works as intended. How can I create several dynamic variables at once? I tried:

```
Table[x[i] = 0; {Checkbox[Dynamic[x[i]], {0, 1}], Dynamic[x[1]]}, {i, 1, 16}]
```

But it doesn't work. Somehow, it creates only one variable and all checkboxes work in a non independent way.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

With initialization:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Array[Dynamic[x[#], Initialization :> (x[_] := 0)] &, 10]
Table[Checkbox[dynamic[x[i]], {0, 1}], {i, 1, 10}] /. 
 dynamic :> Dynamic
```

---

**Original**

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Dynamic[Table[x[i], {i, 1, 10}]]
Table[Checkbox[dynamic[x[i]], {0, 1}], {i, 1, 10}] /. 
 dynamic :> Dynamic
```

Comment: Something odd happens: If I write `Evaluate[Dynamic[Table[x[i] = 0, {i, 1, n}]]]` and suppress the output, it no longer assign values to the `x[i]`. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: `Dynamic` represents a spot on the screen as @Nasser pointed out in [267608](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267608/how-to-add-to-a-dynamic-variable). You can click on the checkbox and manually evaluate the corresponding `x[i]` to see that it is updating values, although since you have suppressed the output, the dynamic display of the table is not there anymore.